# How to read battery level from Arduino while it is powered via 9v Battery barrel jack

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, batterylevel

I would like to know how to read battery level from Arduino while it is powered via 9v Battery barrel jack.

Thanks,
Jyoti RAJ

Comment: What hardware have you connected to let it do so?

Comment: I have Arduino UNO R3 and 9v battery barrel jack only. I want to read battery level.

Comment: No hardware to do it means that no software will help you.

Comment: which hardware can read battery level of arduino? Any suggestions?

Comment: Arduino Uno can measure till 5v on its analog pins. Since you are using 9v battery, its suggested to use voltage divider circuit which can scale down voltage linearly to 5v(max), and then read it.

Comment: I got battery voltage sensor and can read voltage of the battery using arduino. I want to determine if 60% of battery is used up or not. How can we determine if battery is used up 60%? Is simply checking the value 9v *0.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With battery level you mean voltage. You can measure voltage using one of Arduinos analog inputs. As 9V would kill your Arduino you need a voltage divider which allows you to measure a safe voltage that is proportional to the battery voltage.

Comment: I got battery voltage sensor and can read voltage of the battery using arduino. I want to determine if 60% of battery is used up or not. How can we determine if battery is used up 60%? Is simply checking the value 9v *0.6 OK?

Comment: of course not. this would make your devices fail after a few percent as voltage would drop below the necessary level... please read a book on electronics fundamentals. at least do some web search http://www.otherpower.com/otherpower_battery_metering.html

Comment: I understand battery discharge is not linear with voltage but I would like to know approximately how much voltage would drop when measured voltage of battery around the time when it gets 60% consumed?

Comment: What do you mean after some time only voltage will drop to 5.4v when  few percent of battery only got discharged? So even when battery is discharged bit, it will give so less voltage?